# Using FTP commands to download a file with sockets

Tags: sockets, download, ftp, command

I'm using a proprietary programming language and it has no built in `FTP` function. Therefore I'm using `sockets`.

```pascal
sHandle := SocketOpen('ftp.stackoverflow.net', 21);
SocketReadString(sHandle, answer);

retW := SocketWriteString(sHandle, 'user user1673665' & CHR(13) & CHR(10));
SocketReadString(sHandle, answer);
retW := SocketWriteString(sHandle, 'pass !@#$%^&*' & CHR(13) & CHR(10));
SocketReadString(sHandle, answer);

retW := SocketWriteString(sHandle, 'cwd update' & CHR(13) & CHR(10));
SocketReadString(sHandle, answer);
retW := SocketWriteString(sHandle, 'retr update.txt' & CHR(13) & CHR(10));
SocketReadString(sHandle, answer);

SocketClose(sHandle);
```

These are the answers I receive from the `FTP` server:

> 220-Welcome to stackoverflow FTP
>   220 Unauthorized access is illegal!
>   331 Password required for user1673665
>   230 Logged on
>   250 CWD successful. "/update" is current directory.

But why do I get after `retr update.txt` this error:

> 503 Bad sequence of commands.

I'm debugging throught the code step by step. Therefore response time should not be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RETR` command has to be preceded at least by `PASV` or `PORT` to setup a data connection.

Consult [RFC 959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959), particularly the section *"3.2.  Establishing data connections"*

When using the `PASV`, you have to open a connection the port that the server returned in the `227` response.

---

*Also note that the FTP commands shall be sent in uppercase.*

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Martin Prikryl and Steffen Ullrich for your help. I'll add the working code here with comments. Maybe it will be useful for someone. Maybe it's necessary to add sleep commands because the code runs faster than the server responds.

```
# Open control channel
sHandle := SocketOpen('ftp.stackoverflow.net', 21);
SocketReadString(sHandle, answer);
SocketWriteString(sHandle, 'USER user1673665' & CHR(13) & CHR(10));
SocketReadString(sHandle, answer);
SocketWriteString(sHandle, 'PASS !@#$%^&*' & CHR(13) & CHR(10));
SocketReadString(sHandle, answer);
SocketWriteString(sHandle, 'CWD update' & CHR(13) & CHR(10));
SocketReadString(sHandle, answer);
# Enter passive mode and receive data channel adress and port
SocketWriteString(sHandle, 'PASV' & CHR(13) & CHR(10));
SocketReadString(sHandle, answer);
# Create adress for data channel
IF answer <> NOVALUE THEN
  # Split answer on character , and ( and ) and whitespace
  retPASV[] := StrSplit(answer, ',() ');
ENDIF;
CASE retPASV[1]
    # Passive mode is 227
  IS = 227 DO
    connect := retPASV[6] & '.' & retPASV[7] & '.' & retPASV[8] & '.' & retPASV[9];
  IS DO
ENDCASE;
# Create port for data channel
# Port is secondlast number * 256 + last number from PASV reply
port := String2Num(retPASV[10]) * 256 + String2Num(retPASV[11]);
# Open data channel on sHandle2
sHandle2 := SocketOpen(connect, port);
SocketReadString(sHandle2, answer2);
# Download file on control channel
SocketWriteString(sHandle, 'RETR update.txt' & CHR(13) & CHR(10));
SocketReadString(sHandle, Antwort);
# Read file on data channel - result of textfile in string answer2
SocketReadString(sHandle2, answer2);
SocketClose(sHandle);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does `retr update.txt` not work?

Because you are not following the specification of the FTP protocol. Transfer of data is done using a separate TCP connection which needs to be setup beforehand using `PASV`, `EPSV`, `PORT` or `EPRT` commands. For more information, see the standards (that's what they are for), i.e. [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) and [RFC 2428](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2428).